# can't take string data from dialogfragment to sql database due to unresolved string

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, syntax-error

I want to have a dialogfragment take the contact name and number from the user and save it in an sqLite database that I can use to show as a cardview in the main activity.
I tried following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8K-6gdTlGEA&t=232s) tutorial on how to have multiple column entries and add them to your database.

This is the code for the addcontact dialogfragment

```
package com.example.rakshakmk1;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public class Dialog_AddContact extends DialogFragment  {
DatabaseHelper myDB;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // safety check
    if (getDialog() == null) {
        return;
    }

    // set the animations to use on showing and hiding the dialog
    getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    // alternative way of doing it
    //getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().
    //    windowAnimations = R.style.dialog_animation_fade;

    // ... other stuff you want to do in your onStart() method
}


private static final String TAG = "Dialog_AddContact";
public Dialog_AddContact() {
}
public void AddData(String newName,String newNumber){
    boolean insertData = myDB.addData(newName,newNumber);
    if(insertData==true){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Contact Added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Contact not Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public Dialog_AddContact(View source) {
    this.source = source;
}

//widgets
private EditText etName,etPhonenumber ;
private Button btnEnterContact, btnCancel1;
private View source;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_addcontact,container,false);

    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();

    // set "origin" to top left corner, so to speak
    window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);

    // after that, setting values for x and y works "naturally"
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.x = 50;
    params.y = 1000;
    window.setAttributes(params);
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Positioning DialogFragment to: x %d; y %d", params.x, params.y));

    //for rounded corners
    if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
    btnCancel1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel1);
    btnEnterContact = view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnterContact);
    etName =   view.findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etPhonenumber = view.findViewById(R.id.etNumber);

    btnCancel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Closing Dialog");
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
    btnEnterContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Entering Contact");
            if(etName.length() == 0)
            {
                getDialog().dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Invalid Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Contact Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
            if(etPhonenumber.length() == 0)
            {
                getDialog().dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Invalid Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Contact Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String number = etPhonenumber.getText().toString();
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
            if(etName.length()!=0 && etPhonenumber.length()!=0){
                AddData(newName,newNumber);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Invalid Entries",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

and this is the code for the sqLite databasehelper

```
package com.example.rakshakmk1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactlist.db";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contactlist_data";
 public static final String COL1 = "ID";
 public static final String COL2 = "NAME";
 public static final String COL3 = "NUMBER";



public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context){super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "NAME TEXT,NUMBER TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG,"Upgrading database from version"+oldVersion+"to"+ newVersion + ",which will destroy all old data");
    //db.execSQL("DROP_IF_TABLE_EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String newName,String newNumber) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, newName);
    contentValues.put(COL3,newNumber);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
public Cursor getListContents(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}
}
```

Currently I get this error
[image: string error]
even though I have defined it in the databasehelper
[image: defined in the database helper]

I can't seem to figure out the reason why I can't get those string values from the fragment while it seems to work perfectly in the tutorial video.

Any and all help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Variables newName and newNumber do not exist.

I believe that you want:-

```
        if(etName.length()!=0 && etPhonenumber.length()!=0){
            AddData(etName.getText().toString(),etPhonenumber.getText().toString());
        }
```